# What is a complex?

Tags: proteins, muscles

In my text book it says that "Troponin" is a complex of Troponin C, I and T. In this sense, what is the relation between Troponin complex and C, I, T?

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiprotein_complex

Comment: Even a simple "google question" needs to be answered ([ref](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-should-we-deal-with-google-questions)). Also, it is not necessarily easy to go from the word complex that is used everywhere the the biological concept of protein concept. Let's not be too harsh :)

Comment: This is a homework question, please elaborate.

Comment: How about a question from a robotic engineer who does not know anything about biology but wish to understand how the muscle works so to make better robot arms?

Comment: Sounds like a very exciting project! $\ddot \smile$

Comment: @Remi.b no, they do not *need* to be answered. **If** they are answered, they should be answered correctly, which I agree to, instead of posting a link to LMGTFY. However, I think canadianer's comment is a completely sufficient answer, and after it the question can be closed as homework. I don't think this site should be for explaining every single piece of terminology (especially extremely common terminology) that is come across in a paper or textbook. A very important part of learning is being able to find answers for yourself, and not just asking someone to answer it for you.

Comment: @Remi.b - how on earth did you generate that smiley?!

Comment: ha ha `\ddot \smile` gives you $\ddot \smile$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word complex in your sentence designate a `protein complex`, also called `multiprotein complex`.

A protein complex is a group of two or more polypeptide chains that bind together to make up a functional unit. A complex can be made up of similar polypeptide chains or totally different polypeptide chains. Proteasome, Metabolon or hemoglobins are examples.

For more info, have a look at [wiki](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiprotein_complex)

Comment: Are they binded through electrostatic attraction or some sort of chemical compound? How are the "polypeptide chains" connected to each other? i.e. intertwined together

Comment: @IllegalImmigrant For all complexes, various intermolecular forces play a part: electrostatic, van der Waals, hydrophobic. For some complexes, the polypeptide chains are connected by disulfide bonds (covalent). Technically this makes the polypeptide chains one molecule, but they are still called complexes because the individual chains are produced and can sometimes act independently.

Comment: There is this sentence in the introduction of the wiki link: `Proteins in a protein complex are linked by non-covalent protein–protein interactions`. Also, there is an [assembly](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiprotein_complex#Assembly) category in the wiki link. I would expect that different kinds of forces leads the the binding of different pair of proteins. I don't think there is a general rule for that but I know little about biochemistry.

Comment: @canadianer This is pretty mind blowing to think about these tiny little chains in our body is arranged in a way that it binds to other chains in a manner that forms a larger structure called a complex without being pulled apart by trillions of chains, molecules and atoms. Hard to believe that something like this exist but this is the human body after all.

Comment: @IllegalImmigrant Yes, biology is the most interesting and generally best science ;) When you step back and think about this stuff, it's amazing.